# Converting XSD that import multiple XSD to json

Tags: json, import, xsd, schema

I have XSD schema that import other XSD schema.

what is the best way and the best language to convert full XSD into a json request?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to convert from XSD to JSON, you probably mean to be asking how to convert XML to JSON.  To parse from XML to JSON (unmarshal), see [JSONIX](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix).   JSONIX can also serialize JSON to XML (marshal).

In case this isn't exactly what you mean, realize that [XSD](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/) is for validating [***XML***](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/); [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) is for validating [***JSON***](http://www.json.org/).  To convert from XSD to JSON Schema, see [Jsonix Schema Compiler](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix-schema-compiler/wiki).

Comment: If one XSD imports other XSDs, can JSONIX still create the single JSON schema corresponding to all these XSDs ?

Comment: @DeepakBansal: Try it and if you still have a question, please post a new question with details ([mcve] etc) rather than a comment.  Thanks.